# Adding slide transition to view that already has flip animation?

Tags: animation, swiftui, transition

I have a flashcard activity, I pulled some code off of here to incorporate a card flip animation as this level of swiftUI was a bit over my pay grade.

However, I would also like to add a slide transition of the 'card' in my view. From left to center of screen or from right to center of screen, depending on if the user clicks the forward or back button.

Is this possible?

```
struct flashCardActivity: View {
    
    @State var flashCardObj: flashCardObject
    
    @State  var flipped = false
    @State  var animate3d = false
    @State  var showButtonSet = false
    
    @State  var counter: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            progressBar(counter: self.$counter, totalCards: flashCardObj.words.count)
                .padding(.top, 175)
                .padding(.bottom, 80)
            
            Spacer()
            
            
            cardView(flipped: self.$flipped, animate3d: self.$animate3d, counter: self.$counter, flashCardObj: self.$flashCardObj)
            
            rightWrongButtonSet().padding(.top, 20)
            saveToMyListButton().padding(.top, 25)
            
            nextPreviousButtonSet(fcO: self.$flashCardObj, counter: self.$counter).offset(y:50)
            
            
            
        }.offset(y:-80)
        
    }
}

struct cardView: View {
    
    @Binding var flipped: Bool
    @Binding var animate3d: Bool
    @Binding var counter: Int
    @Binding var flashCardObj: flashCardObject
    
    var body: some View{
        ZStack() {
            flashCardItal(counter: $counter, fcO: $flashCardObj).opacity(flipped ? 0.0 : 1.0)
            flashCardEng(counter: $counter, fcO: $flashCardObj).opacity(flipped ? 1.0 : 0.0)
        }
        .modifier(FlipEffect(flipped: $flipped, angle: animate3d ? 180 : 0, axis: (x: 1, y: 0)))
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.8)) {
                self.animate3d.toggle()
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct FlipEffect: GeometryEffect {
    
    var animatableData: Double {
        get { angle }
        set { angle = newValue }
    }
    
    @Binding var flipped: Bool
    var angle: Double
    let axis: (x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat)
    
    func effectValue(size: CGSize) -> ProjectionTransform {
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.flipped = self.angle >= 90 && self.angle < 270
        }
        
        let tweakedAngle = flipped ? -180 + angle : angle
        let a = CGFloat(Angle(degrees: tweakedAngle).radians)
        
        var transform3d = CATransform3DIdentity;
        transform3d.m34 = -1/max(size.width, size.height)
        
        transform3d = CATransform3DRotate(transform3d, a, axis.x, axis.y, 0)
        transform3d = CATransform3DTranslate(transform3d, -size.width/2.0, -size.height/2.0, 0)
        
        let affineTransform = ProjectionTransform(CGAffineTransform(translationX: size.width/2.0, y: size.height / 2.0))
        
        return ProjectionTransform(transform3d).concatenating(affineTransform)
    }
}

struct flashCardItal: View {
    
    @Binding var counter: Int
    @Binding var fcO: flashCardObject
    
    var body: some View{
        Text(fcO.words[counter].wordItal)
            .font(Font.custom("Marker Felt", size: 40))
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            .frame(width: 325, height: 250)
            .background(Color.teal)
            .cornerRadius(20)
            .shadow(radius: 10)
            .padding(.bottom, 30)
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 10)
            .zIndex(1)
        
        
        
    }
}

struct flashCardEng: View {
    
    @Binding var counter: Int
    @Binding var fcO: flashCardObject
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text(fcO.words[counter].wordEng)
                .font(Font.custom("Marker Felt", size: 40))
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .padding(.bottom, 30)
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 10)
            
            
            Text(fcO.words[counter].gender.rawValue)
                .font(Font.custom("Marker Felt", size: 30))
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .padding(.top, 2)
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 10)
            
        } .frame(width: 325, height: 250)
            .background(Color.teal)
            .cornerRadius(20)
            .shadow(radius: 10)
    }
}

struct rightWrongButtonSet: View{
    var body: some View{
        
        HStack{
            
            Button(action: {
                
            }, label:
                    {Image("cancel")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
                
                
                
            }).padding(.leading, 80)
            
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {
                
            }, label:
                    {Image("checked")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
                
                
            }).padding(.trailing, 80)
            
        }
        
    }
}

struct saveToMyListButton: View{
    var body: some View{
        Button(action: {}, label: {Text("Save to My List")})
    }
}

struct nextPreviousButtonSet: View{
    
    @Binding var fcO: flashCardObject
    @Binding var counter: Int
    
    var body: some View{
        HStack{
            Button(action: {
                if counter > 0 {
                    counter = counter - 1
                    
                }
            }, label:
                    {Image(systemName: "arrow.backward").resizable()
                    .bold()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                
                
                
            }).padding(.leading, 90)
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {
                if counter < fcO.words.count - 1 {
                    counter = counter + 1
                }
            }, label:
                    {Image(systemName: "arrow.forward").resizable()
                    .bold()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                
                
                
            }).padding(.trailing, 90)
        }
    }
}

struct progressBar: View {
    
    @Binding var counter: Int
    let totalCards: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Text(String(counter) + "/" + String(totalCards)).offset(y:20)
            
            ProgressView("", value: Double(counter), total: Double(totalCards))
                .frame(width: 300).cornerRadius(10)
                .scaleEffect(x: 1, y: 4)
            
            
        }
    }
}

struct flashCardActivity_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        flashCardActivity(flashCardObj: flashCardObject.Food)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am able to get the view to somewhat animate. Adding withAnimation onto the forward/back buttons and then a .slide transition on a VStack holding cardView(). I can see the animation of the words changing but the frame is not sliding.

Comment: figured out a solution, I think he proper approach to this is to incorporate a horizontal scroll view. So I switched everything to that and got exactly what I wanted

Comment: GeometryEffect is the most practical solution

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get something working. I see you just found your own solution so you might not be interested any more.

The way this solution works is to use a `ZStack` to show previous/current/next cards. The arrows change the context, with animation. When the current view has disappeared, an `.onDisappear` callback causes the current to be replaced with previous or next, whichever is now showing.

Recommend trying in a simulator, it works better than in the preview.

Here you go:

```swift
enum Gender: String {
    case masculine = "m"
    case feminine = "f"
}

struct Word {
    let wordEng: String
    let wordItal: String
    let gender: Gender
}

struct flashCardObject {
    static let Food = flashCardObject(words: [
        Word(wordEng: "apple", wordItal: "mela", gender: .feminine),
        Word(wordEng: "tomato", wordItal: "pomodoro", gender: .masculine),
        Word(wordEng: "biscuit", wordItal: "biscotto", gender: .masculine),
        Word(wordEng: "meringue", wordItal: "meringa", gender: .feminine),
        Word(wordEng: "cherry", wordItal: "ciliegia", gender: .feminine)
    ])
    let words: [Word]
}

enum Position {
    case previous
    case current
    case next
}

struct flashCardActivity: View {

    @State var flashCardObj: flashCardObject
    @State  var showButtonSet = false
    @State  var counter: Int = 0
    @State var position = Position.current

    // Moves previous or next to current
    private func updateCurrent() {
        if position == .previous {
            counter = counter - 1
        } else if position == .next {
            counter = counter + 1
        }
        position = .current
    }

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            progressBar(counter: counter, totalCards: flashCardObj.words.count)
                .padding(.top, 175)
                .padding(.bottom, 80)

            Spacer()

            ZStack {
                if position == .previous && counter > 0 {
                    cardView(word: flashCardObj.words[counter - 1])
                        .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                } else if position == .next && counter < flashCardObj.words.count - 1 {
                    cardView(word: flashCardObj.words[counter + 1])
                        .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
                } else {
                    cardView(word: flashCardObj.words[counter])
                        .onDisappear(perform: updateCurrent)
                }
            }
            rightWrongButtonSet().padding(.top, 20)
            saveToMyListButton().padding(.top, 25)

            nextPreviousButtonSet(position: $position).offset(y:50)

        }
        .offset(y:-80)
    }
}

struct cardView: View {

    @State var flipped = false
    @State var animate3d = false
    let word: Word

    var body: some View{
        ZStack() {
            flashCardEng(word: word).opacity(flipped ? 0.0 : 1.0)
            flashCardItal(word: word).opacity(flipped ? 1.0 : 0.0)
        }
        .modifier(FlipEffect(flipped: $flipped, angle: animate3d ? 180 : 0, axis: (x: 1, y: 0)))
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.8)) {
                self.animate3d.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FlipEffect: GeometryEffect {

    var animatableData: Double {
        get { angle }
        set { angle = newValue }
    }

    @Binding var flipped: Bool
    var angle: Double
    let axis: (x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat)

    func effectValue(size: CGSize) -> ProjectionTransform {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.flipped = self.angle >= 90 && self.angle < 270
        }

        let tweakedAngle = flipped ? -180 + angle : angle
        let a = CGFloat(Angle(degrees: tweakedAngle).radians)

        var transform3d = CATransform3DIdentity;
        transform3d.m34 = -1/max(size.width, size.height)

        transform3d = CATransform3DRotate(transform3d, a, axis.x, axis.y, 0)
        transform3d = CATransform3DTranslate(transform3d, -size.width/2.0, -size.height/2.0, 0)

        let affineTransform = ProjectionTransform(CGAffineTransform(translationX: size.width/2.0, y: size.height / 2.0))

        return ProjectionTransform(transform3d).concatenating(affineTransform)
    }
}

struct flashCardEng: View {

    let word: Word

    var body: some View{
        Text(word.wordEng)
            .font(Font.custom("Marker Felt", size: 40))
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            .frame(width: 325, height: 250)
            .background(Color.teal)
            .cornerRadius(20)
            .shadow(radius: 10)
            .padding(.bottom, 30)
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 10)
            .zIndex(1)
    }
}

struct flashCardItal: View {

    let word: Word

    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text(word.wordItal)
                .font(Font.custom("Marker Felt", size: 40))
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .padding(.bottom, 30)
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 10)

            Text(word.gender.rawValue)
                .font(Font.custom("Marker Felt", size: 30))
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .padding(.top, 2)
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 10)

        } .frame(width: 325, height: 250)
            .background(Color.teal)
            .cornerRadius(20)
            .shadow(radius: 10)
    }
}

struct rightWrongButtonSet: View{
    var body: some View{

        HStack{

            Button(
                action: {},
                label: {
                    Image("cancel")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
                }
            )
            .padding(.leading, 80)

            Spacer()

            Button(
                action: {},
                label: {
                    Image("checked")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
                }
            ).padding(.trailing, 80)
        }
    }
}

struct saveToMyListButton: View{
    var body: some View{
        Button(action: {}, label: {Text("Save to My List")})
    }
}

struct nextPreviousButtonSet: View{

    @Binding var position: Position

    var body: some View{
        HStack{
            Button(
                action: {
                    withAnimation { position = .previous }
                },
                label: {
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.backward")
                        .resizable()
                        .bold()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                }
            ).padding(.leading, 90)

            Spacer()

            Button(
                action: {
                    withAnimation { position = .next }
                },
                label: {
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.forward")
                        .resizable()
                        .bold()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                }
            ).padding(.trailing, 90)
        }
    }
}

struct progressBar: View {

    let counter: Int
    let totalCards: Int

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Text(String(counter) + "/" + String(totalCards)).offset(y:20)

            ProgressView("", value: Double(counter + 1), total: Double(totalCards))
                .frame(width: 300).cornerRadius(10)
                .scaleEffect(x: 1, y: 4)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        flashCardActivity(flashCardObj: flashCardObject.Food)
    }
}
```

Other comments:

- I improvised the parts that were missing (in particular, `flashCardObject`)
- I have avoided using bindings for values that are read-only. I would suggest, you only need a `Binding` if you want to update the variable from the nested context.
- I changed the progress bar to show `counter + 1`.
- I switched the language in the flash cards, because I didn't understand why you needed to show gender against an English word.
- I couldn't see the `rightWrongButtonSet` when running on an iPhone 14, I didn't investigate why not.
- I resisted the temptation to alter the layout, but I would suggest you should try not to use `.offset` for layout positioning (get the padding right instead).

Comment: thank you, I appreciate the comments. I'm still learning best practices so the notes will help me improve the performance of my project.